# Using XmlIgnoreAttribute to Ignore Base Class Property

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have an abstract base class to which I have added some virtual properties. What I would like is to, in my derived class, specify that a particular base class property be ignored during the serialization(and deserialization process). As you see below, the `Value`-property in `BaseClass`-class is declared a `virtual` property, and in the `DerivedClass`-class, using the `overrides`-keyword, I have chosen to override the base class's ppty and then put the `XmlIgnoreAttribute`-Attribute over it. However, when I test the code, I still find the `Value` ppty included in the generated XML for my derived class instance. Same thing happens with the Definition ppty, it is rendered even though I hide it in the Derived class using the new keyword, and then apply the XMLIgnoreAttribute to it as well. What is wrong with the code below please?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual String Value { get; set; }

     public String Definition { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("SeparatorCharacter")]
    public virtual String SeparatorCharacter { get; set; }
}


public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public overrides String Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("FillerCharacter")]
    public String FillValue { get; set; }

     [XmlIgnore()]
    public new String Definition { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what are your de/serialization-calls? to which class/type-info?

Comment: where is your `: BaseClass`?

Comment: @kobojunkie Instead of overrides have you tried new?  public new String Value { get; set; }

Comment: yeah, I have tried new as well. That did not change the outcome at all. So I am trying here to gain a deeper understanding of how this atribute, and or any others can be used to achieve the goal I hope to here.

Answer (score 6):

The serializer will not consider the attribute on the override property, whether you supply it with an attribute or through `XmlAttributeOverrides`. The only partial workaround to obtain the behavior you want is to add a virtual `ShouldSerializeValue` method to the base class and override it in the derived class to suppress the serialization of `Value`. This won't prevent deserialization of `Value`, but you can make the override setter empty.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual String Foo { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeFoo () { return true ; }
}

public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public override String Foo { get; set; }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeFoo () { return false ; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please further explain this please. Do I need to have my base class inherit an interface or something for this ShouldSerializeValue method to be called?

Comment: No, it is a purely name-based convention. Updated answer.

Comment: In the case that I have more than one property in my base class, what happens when the return in the derived class is false? Will all the properties in the base class be ignored?

Comment: No, each ShouldSerialize method is for one property, the one it's named after. Hope the edit clears things up.